# Update SQL Query with Join on 2 tables

Tags: oracle, join

I have a requirement to read from 2 tables once read i have to update the falg on both table.

My SQL query

```
SELECT t1.KUNNR,t1.SETT_KEY,t1.QUART_START,t1.QUART_END,t2.PAY_METH,t2.MAT_NDC,t2.AMOUNT   
FROM TSAP_REBATE_MEDI t1  
INNER JOIN  TSAP_REBATE_LINE t2  ON  t1.KUNNR=t2.KUNNR AND t1.SETT_KEY=t2.SETT_KEY  
WHERE  t1.PROCESSING_STATUS = 'N' AND t2.PROCESSING_STATUS = 'N'
```

This is working fine now i need an update query for the same where PROCESSING_STATUS is set to 'P' on both tables.

Comment: You should really decide which database you are using.  MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle are three rather different products.

Comment: Sorry i have changed it ..I am using oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update two tables at the same time.  Run two separate `UPDATE` statements of the following nature

```
UPDATE t1  
SET COLUMN = VALUE
FROM TSAP_REBATE_MEDI t1
INNER JOIN  TSAP_REBATE_LINE t2  
    ON  t1.KUNNR=t2.KUNNR 
    AND t1.SETT_KEY=t2.SETT_KEY  
WHERE  t1.PROCESSING_STATUS = 'N' 
    AND t2.PROCESSING_STATUS = 'N'
    /* Add any other conditions */
```

However, if you want them both to be updated (or neither one), wrap both updates in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION - COMMIT`

Comment: its throwing the error command not properly ended,ITS a ORACLE DB